# Why does my php script creates a new long URL?

Tags: php, url

my php script creates for some reason a super long new URL.
My original URL looks like this

http://someserveryoudon'tneedtoknow/index.php

And this is what I get after running the script.

http://someserveryoudon'tneedtoknow/index.php?vorname=and&nachname=andasd&ort=asd&email=asd&sonstiges=+Bitte+nur+ausfuellen+wenn+%27Sonstiges%27+ausgewaehlt+wurde+&sonstiges=&sonstiges=&sonstiges=&sonstiges=&sonstiges=

The script is about typing some data in some windows. And the weird words standing in the long URL are german words. Maybe important about them is that they are used in my script as messages standing in some textboxes. And some of them are variables.

Do you know what I can do to make php stop this? (At least I guess it's php's fault)

Yanakin

Comment: `http://someserveryoudon'tneedtoknow/index.php` is not a valid URL. Use `example.org` for the domain name, this is why it exists.

Comment: *"At least I guess it's php's fault"* -- only if Php is your middle name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you pass data using get parameter. so that is why your url have a data like email is asd and so on..

Comment: Ok. Can I solve it using the post parameter or what should I do?

Comment: yes. you should use post parameter instead. you can use get parameter for certain situation only, such as passing a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

These are GET parameters. You should use POST to avoid this. POST is recommended anyway.

## Reasons why you should use POST

### It's secure

These parameters can be stored anywhere. POST doesn't store parameters in the URL. It sends the parameters in data. It can possibly stop some attacks.

```
GET /signup.php?username=john&password=johnny1234567890 HTTP/1.1
```

or

```
POST /signup.php HTTP/1.1

username=john&password=johnny1234567890
```

What seems better?

It's stored all on your computer. In your browsing history. Everywhere!

### It's shorter

Not everyone wants to see https://example.com/signup.php?username=john&password=johnny1234567890&confidentialstuff=105650970950940 in the URL.